# What can I use to render 3D images (OBJ, PLY) in my GUI application with color?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, vtk, point-cloud-library

I just went through VTK, as well as the PCL Visualizer, and have not been able to display a full PLY image. All that is displayed is the geometry like so:

[image]

Any input about libraries and usage?

Comment: Are you asking for an application that does this, or how to write one?

Comment: I'm looking for an API I could use to integrate a reader/visualizer into my Qt application.

Comment: Do you have an example of the file you are trying to import?  What is in there besides vertex and face lists?

Comment: What do you mean when talking about a 3D image (especially when using it to refer to geometry files, like OBJ or PLY). What else do you expect from a PLY file other than geometry? I know PLY files can be used for anything, but in this case it could also just contain a database for observing planetary movement and you might have to explain a bit clearer what you really expect it to contain besides geometry.

Comment: Did you try [pcl::io::loadPLYFile](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rolled my own PLY reader from [Paul Bourke's 3D site](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/).  At the top of this page are links to code.  This site is great for things 3D in general.  It looks as though once you go beyond the usual vertex pool/indexed face set each application can specify different properties for things.  This is probably why you can't find a standard tool to read other properties.  I only care about geometry myself so I never worried about color.

[This](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/Joao.Oliveira/ply.html) site has code though I haven't checked it.

I use [Coin and SoQt](http://www.coin3d.org/) in my Qt apps for visualization.  Coin is a Free implementation of Open Inventor.  Coin comes with a 3DS reader and a reader for Inventor and VRML and X3D.

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) will read PLY and then you can write to a large number of files such as Inventor.

Comment: Could you use something like meshlab to convert it to a more convenient format? Ply is a bit variable when it comes to material properties and lighting/colors

Comment: Martin, is there a more stable alternative you have in mind?

Comment: Inventor, VRML, X3D, 3DS have standardized material formats.  Many tools can read these.

Comment: Thank you, these helped a lot. HEre's something else that I found incredibly useful as well in case anyone happens to stumble upon this thread while googling:  http://code.google.com/p/miminect/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpcl_qt_vtk%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the link and for pointing out the PCL world to me.

Answer (score 3):

[Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) lets you read PLY, OBJ and many others. It also has a standalone viewer, and many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/), which is built on top of the VTK libraries, or [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/)? These are both open source visualisation applications which can handle numerous file formats, including VTK and PLY, and are designed to visualise huge datasets (with colour!). They can both be used as standalone applications or incorporated into existing code.